# Amazon Athena - Convert String to Date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, date-formatting

I would like to convert some dates stored as a string to a date. The data looks as follows: *26APR2017:06:01:44*. I would prefer it to be in any regular date format.

Can someone please help me to convert this to a date format? I'm sure the dateparse function is useful here and have used it before but am unsure how to adjust it for this particular data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use date_parse() to parse and date() to cast timestamp retunred from parse function to date.

`select date_parse('26APR2017:06:01:44','%d%b%Y:%H:%i:%s')` will give you

```
2017-04-26 06:01:44.000
```

`select date(date_parse('26APR2017:06:01:44','%d%b%Y:%H:%i:%s'))` will give you

```
2017-04-26
```